# Boombox power transformer designed for air cooling, wise to tape it down?

Tags: transformer

[image]

My olde faithful boombox was dropped too many times (pictured above).  When I move the boombox, something heavy moves freely around inside.  I manage to remove the top and saw that a power transformer had broken off its two mounting posts:

[image]

The transformer is occupies the upper right half of the photo.  You can see the two metal wing flanges with the mounting holes.  The transformer's perch is at the bottom left.  The two broken mounting posts are plastic and look like they are part of the plastic moulding of the sidewall.

I want to bind the transformer to the remnants of its perch using duct tape.  But it sure looks the the original design of the perch was to keep the metal sides, top, and bottom exposed to air as much as possible.  This suggests to me that the transformer gets hot, and that it may not be wise to cover it up and bind it to anything.  The two big fat red wires at the front are fed directly from the power cord (120V here).

I'm on the hunt for a replacement, but it is such a shame to contribute to the landfill for a problem like fixing the position of the transformer.  **From a professional perspective, considering the apparent design attempts to keep the transformer aired out, would it be prudent to chuck this old faithful beast?**

Comment: I would attempt to secure the transformer somehow, rather than covering it with tape.  There may be enough "meat" left in the original mounting posts to hold it, or you could mount it with machine screws and nuts through the case.

Comment: @Pete Bennet:  I pondered it for about an hour.  The posts need their original elevation in order for the transformer to be raised for airing purposes.  I pondered epoxying the broken parts of the posts back on, then drilling new holes for the screws.  But it's plastic, and I doubt that I could secure the broken bits well enough for the curing time. Also, I live in a small apartment with wall-to-wall carpeting and limited surface space.  The drilling would create a mess.  After much humming and hawing, the only practical way ahead seems to be tape. The only risk to assess is the cooling.

Comment: By the way, could you please elaborate on "mount it with machine screws and nuts through the case"?  The current perch keeps the transformer away from the sidewall.

Comment: Hot glue, double side glue tape comes in the mind. Duct tape is the last thing.

Comment: The posts look like they have holes in them.  Find some screws that fit the holes and screw it back in place.

Comment: My concern with taping the post ends back onto the nubs is that it's hard to get one's finger in there.  That's why epoxy came to mind, but it would be risky, and I'd have to drill holes to screw into.  As for screwing the battery back in place, the nubs are too short right now, so the transformer won't be as elevated as it was, meaning less airing out.  What I might do is to find longer screws, screw through the broken off portion of the mounting post, and then into the nubs themselves.  Maybe put some glue between the broken bits and the nub.

Comment: I'm not even sure that the thing will still work once I did  that, but worth a try.

Comment: Transformers like that are generally mounted directly on a panel or chassis - I doubt if any consideration of ventilation was given in designing the mounting location.  The posts would be provided mainly to ensure the mounting screws didn't go through the case.

Comment: Interesting.  Because it almost seems that it was deliberate in this case.  Perhaps I will simply bin it to the perch in the most convenient way.  Thanks.